# local scope in switch case

Tags: c++

I saw some surprising code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    auto myDummy = [](int i){
    switch(i){
        case 0: return 0;
        case 1:{
            std::cout << "Evaluated 1\n";
            if(i == 1){
                return 1;
            }
            case 2:
            std::cout << "Evaluated 2\n";
            return 2;
        }
        break;
        default: return -1;
    }
    };
    std::cout << myDummy(1) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles and run without warning. The bracket of case 1{} seems to be ignored.

> myDummy(1)
>
> -> 1
>
> myDummy(2)
>
> -> 2

If I modify the code for case 1 to be:

```
             case 1:{
                std::cout << "Evaluated 1\n";
                int a = i;
                if(a == 1){
                    return 1;
                }
                case 2:
                std::cout << "Evaluated 2\n";
                return 2;
            }
            break;
```

then it does not compile anymore:

> prog.cpp:16:13: error: jump to case label [-fpermissive]
>
> ```
>     case 2:
>
>          ^ prog.cpp:12:21: note:   crosses initialization of 'int a'
>
>              int a = i;
> ```

The brackets for case 1:{}break; do not cancel the switch context. It just creates a local scope for variable.
But this is really obfuscating.
Why such a behaviour?

Comment: Your `case2` is _inside_ `case1`, why?

Comment: Why is legacy code legacy?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall  Because you can.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device  Doesn't mean it's a good idea for writing clear, maintainable code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, Interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what the standard says about a `switch` (§6.4.2, emphasis mine):

> 2 - **Any statement** within the
>   switch
>   statement can be labeled with one or more case labels as
>   follows:
>   case
>   constant-expression
>   :
>   where the
>   constant-expression
>   shall be a converted constant expression (
>   5.19
>   ) of the promoted type of the
>   switch condition.
>
> <...>
>
> 5 - When the
>   switch
>   statement is executed, its condition is evaluated and compared with each case constant. If
>   one of the case constants is equal to the value of the condition, control is passed to the statement following
>   the matched case label

So the `switch` doesn't care where exactly the cases are, the following works:

```
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    switch(i)
    {
        case 1:
        {
        case 2:
            {
                if(false)
                {
                    case 0:
                        std::cout << "hello there!"; //yes it will print
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Regarding the modification you propose, check my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578936/getting-a-bunch-of-crosses-initialization-error/11578973#11578973). Basically with

```
case 1:{
    std::cout << "Evaluated 1\n";
    int a = i;
    if(a == 1){
            return 1;
    }
    case 2:
    //here a is in scope
    std::cout << "Evaluated 2\n";
    return 2;
 }
```

you can jump to `case2` without actually creating `a`, but `a` will still be in scope.

Answer (score 3):

`switch` to a label works in an identical way to `goto` with a label when it comes to moving to a different scope block.

You should take care when adopting such a scheme, in particular with regards to reading uninitialised variables, the behaviour of which is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You can place a scope anywhere:

```
int main() {
    int a;
    {
        int a; // in a more local scope.
    }
}
```

But you can't put a variable initialization in a scope where it would be visible by more than 2 cases of a switch:

```
int main() {
    int b;
    switch(1) {
    case 0:
        int a = 0; // error
        break;
    case 1:
        b = a; // what happens?
        break;
    }
}
```

Finally, there's nothing wrong with a case label inside another scope (as long as it would not violate our second rule, there):

```
int main() {
  switch(1) {
  case 1: {
    break;
  case 2:
    break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: fair... let me reformulate then: Doesn t it surprise you that case2 is taken into account?

Comment: well, partially, thanks. my surprise was to see case2 being actually treated, while it was in a nested scope. My ignorance of how a switch work was the problem. I appreciate the explanation about variable initialization though. thanks.

Comment: There is plenty of wrong with a case inside the scope of another case. There is never a reason to use such obscure program design, just because the language allows it doesn't make it good practice.

Comment: @Lundin I didn't say it was a good practice. By saying "There's nothing wrong" I just meant that this is perfectly legal C++.