# crosses initialization error in switch case statement

Tags: c++, initialization, switch-statement, case

I've got the following code:

```cpp
Class A {
  public:
    A::A(const char* name):
      _name(name)
      {}
    virtual void doSomething();
  private:
    const char* _name;
}

Class B : public A {
  B::B(const char* name):
    A(name)
    {}
  void doSomething() {
    //do something
  }
}
```

So far so good, but I've experiencing an error `crosses initialization of B* newB` in the following code:

```cpp
std::vector<A*> vectorOfAs;

switch (enumType) {
  case enum1 :  
    B* newB = new B("foobar");
    vectorOfAs.push_back(newB);
    break;
  case enum2 :
    C* newC = new C("barfoo");
    vectorOfAs.push_back(newC);
    break;
}
```

Why the error?

Some background:
I want to store pointers of derived classes in a vector for easy searching/iterating. The names are unique so I can iterate through the vector and look for the pointer which points to the object with the right name. When calling a method from a pointed-to object, the inherited one should be called (`//do something`).

Edit: @François Andrieux: you're right. made (serious) typo.
Changed `Class B : public B` to `Class B: public A`

Comment: Sounds like you have a `goto` or improperly braced `swith` statement.  Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: `Class B : public B` Seems like you wanted `Class B : public A` ?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Not to mention doSomething should be declared pure virtual in A, and the methods in B are all private.  Like Nathan asked for, the actual code that is being compiled would be great.

Comment: You can have your `std::vector<A*>`, and then store derived class objects in it. `B newB = new B("foobar")` instead of `B*`

Comment: Indeed, the new objects are generated inside a switch/case. I also edited the Class B : public A statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newB` is in the scope of the switch statement, which makes it available in all switch cases, but won't be initialised in all of them. You should enclose each case in its own local scope (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11578973/4304) for more information):

```
switch (enumType) {
  case enum1 : 
  {
    B* newB = new B("foobar");
    vectorOfAs.push_back(newB);
    break;
  }
  case enum2 :
  {
    C* newC = new C("barfoo");
    vectorOfAs.push_back(newB);
    break;
  }
}
```

At which point you will get a compiler error in enum2 (thereby exposing a bug), in that you are pushing newB not newC, which is what I assume you intended:

```
switch (enumType) {
  case enum1 : 
  {
    B* newB = new B("foobar");
    vectorOfAs.push_back(newB);
    break;
  }
  case enum2 :
  {
    C* newC = new C("barfoo");
    vectorOfAs.push_back(newC); // <--
    break;
  }
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Works! I sure would have had to give more info to the previous helpers as NathanOliver was spot on!