# Why can you define a variable in a switch statement under 'default' but not under 'case'

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I [understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement) why I can't define a variable under 'case', but why can I define one under 'default' then? I thought it was another label, just like 'case'.

```
switch(myVar)
{
    case 0:
        int a = 12; //error
        break;
    default:
        int b = 42; //OK
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try reordering your cases:

```
switch(myVar)
{
    default:
        int b = 42; // error
        break;
    case 0:
        int a = 12; // ok
}
```

Now you will see the compiler complain about `b`, and not `a`. There is nothing magical about `default`, it's just that if you define the variable in the last case statement, then there is no way to skip over the initialization of that variable, and so it is perfectly fine to do so.

You can always scope your cases, so that the variables can't be accessed outside of a case, if that was your intention:

```
switch(myVar)
{
    case 0: {
        int a = 12;
    }
    break;
    default:
        int b = 42;
}
```

Comment: I obviously didn't understand the OP's confusion :) +1

Comment: I had never considered that `default` could be anything but the last case in a switch.

Answer (score 3):

You can't define it under `case 0` because a jump to the default label ([which is what a switch statement does](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch)) will skip the initialization of `a`.

C++ forbids such skipping. If there's variable being initialized in a block, then control cannot go to a point inside the block that is past the initialization, without preforming it.

However, since `int` is a type without a constructor, then you can define the variable if you omit the initializer:

```
switch(myvar)
{
    case 0:
        int a; //OK too
        break;
    default:
        int b = 42; //OK
}
```

Comment: So how's 'default' different?

Comment: @Valentin - Different how, you mean?

Comment: Nvm, @Rakete1111 nailed it

Answer (score 0):

Initialize all your variable before the switch statement.

```
int a = 0;
switch(myVar)
{
    case 0:
        a = 12; //now ok
        break;
    default:
        int b = 42; //OK
}
```

It has got something to do with C++ standard. 
More info here [Cross initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578936/getting-a-bunch-of-crosses-initialization-error)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that:

```
switch(myVar)
{
    case 0:
    {
        int a = 0;
    }
    break;
    default:
        int b = 42; //OK
}
```